# Magento Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'MYSITE_magento'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento

I have copied a magento site from one server to another, hoping to make a carbon copy of a shop.

I exported/imported the database via phpMyAdmin and I zipped and unzipped the site files.

Everything is there. I have doubled checked the db passwords and details. I have also checked all of the file/folder permissions are correct. Still I get the error.

This error says ...

```
 There has been an error processing your request
 Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
```

Here are the contents of my Magento error log:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:97:
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'MYSITE_magento'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
;i:1;s:2792:"
#0 /home/MYSITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/MYSITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(251): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/MYSITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(448): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/MYSITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/MYSITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Type/Db/Pdo/Mysql.php(45): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql->getConnection(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_read')
#8 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(312): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->_getConnection('read')
#9 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(332): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#10 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Collection/Abstract.php(97): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#11 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1206): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Website))
#12 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1239): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_mysql4/web...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Website))
#13 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/Mage.php(460): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Website))
#14 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Website))
#15 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#16 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(532): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#17 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(393): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#18 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(299): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#19 /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /home/MYSITE/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
";s:3:"url";s:10:"/~MYSITE/";s:11:"script_name";s:19:"/~MYSITE/index.php";}
```

Obviously I replaced my site name above with MYSITE.

Comment: check your db username and password correctly and put those in local.xml accordingly

Comment: that user has no access to database

Comment: Hi Guys - I've checked all these. Still no joy. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No ideas needed...its the only way here..either username dont have proper permission,or username is wrong or database name is not correct or db host name is wrong

Comment: its already showing there "Access denied for user 'MYSITE_magento'@'localhost'"

Comment: paste your local.xml here

Comment: try removing local.xml file and flushing cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be created for `local.xml .`First,check  `database username ,database name,datauser password`..... etc in local.xml (path `yourmagentodir/app/etc/`)

Check there have any `local.xml.bak`.If exits then `delet`e  local.xml.bak.

check database `permission issue for database user.`

Clear cache from  cache folder (path `yourmagentodir/var/cache/`)

Comment: Hi Guys - I've checked all these. Still no joy. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: it must be database access related issue... can be host

Answer (score 0):

It was in deed a corrupt database. Thanks for drilling this into me guys as it forced me to keep rechecking the db